# Qt : multipage GUI in one static window

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I want to create a GUI with several pages, but creating separate forms and showing them for example by clicking on buttons, opens new window and I don't want that. Closing last window and opening the new form also has problems like it moves and I don't want that. I know I can use QWizard, but my GUI is not a wizard really!

My first page is a login page, but I don't want to show that by a dialog and the simultaneously  `mainwindow` existing in the background! I want something like what we can see for example in android apps.

How can I create that?!

Comment: QStackedWidget might give you what you want; it lets you specify a "stack" of widgets that all occupy the same space on screen, and shows whichever widget you move to the 'top' of the stack.

Comment: thanks @JeremyFriesner .let me try that and will be back.